# DLL injection for browser alone

Tags: c++, sockets, dll, exe, createremotethread

I want to be able to type www.mydomain.com into my web browser but have the actual traffic go to something.mydomain.com. I thought to, maybe inject a dll into the process browser(firefox.exe). I tried to use some methods like hooking, dll injection using create remote thread etc. But, since I'm a newbie, especially when it comes to C++ or Assembly level languages, I coudn't understand much about it. The one's I could understand are no longer compatible with Win 7 or higherCould someone help me by directing me in the right path. 
All I want is know how to intercept/manipulate an outgoing URL request from the browser. I found that TCP/IP first creates some socket using socket() function and then connect() function. I sthere a way to intercept that?
I want this to be easy, simple and compatible with windows XP to 10. If it's not easy I'm okay with building different codes for different versions. If the script is cross platform, it would be even more awesome.

Comment: Why not just use your hosts file?

Comment: I don't want to just map a hostt name to IP. I wan't to dynamically ridirect one url to another. Say www.google.co.us to www.facebook.com in localhost(My PC) not in the server. Preferabbly in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you want to do (or more precisely the way you want to do it) is possible without being the owner of the domain and setting a HTTP redirect on the server.

Modifying the hosts file or setting up your own DNS server and having the machine or its router use that to resolve DNS queries is really the only way but...

Dependant on the browser this may not be possible.  Current versions of firefox and chrome implement dns prefetching which essentially means that they come preloaded with a bunch of popular dns entries for faster page loading times.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.I found a firefox extension called 'Redirector' which does what I need, well almost. I could essentially redirect any site to the one I want. The code was in Java *script mostly, but since I'm a noob I couldn't understand it much. So, I'm trying to learn it from scratch with the aim to create an extension/app just like it but with remote installation and maybe a way to enter or change arguments remotely. Would that be easy to implent? How should I go about it for chrome and firefox? Suggest me in the right path